# Auto email all rows of Google sheet that meet a certain condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have modified a code I found online to look at a google sheet (sample below) and send an email when an employee's work permit is about to expire in 30 days.

However, I would like to modify it to send one email (to one email address) with a table of all the employees whose permit is about to expire instead of one email per employee. Please help !

[Sample of google sheet format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kSTi.png)

```
function emailReminderAlert() {

  // getting data from spreadsheet
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var startRow = 2; // Ignore the column headings and frozen rows
   var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; // Get the last number of row that has content with excluding header rows
   var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn(); // Get the last number of column that has content.

  //Get data range dynamically
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    //console.log(row[3]);
    var today = new Date(), // today's date
    exp_date = row[3] // exp date

    var cert_details = 
        {
          employee_name:row[0],
          passport_number:row[1],
          renewal_date: row[2],
          email_primary:row[4],
        };

    //Remove the time part from the date
    var t2 = new Date(exp_date);
    t2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var t1 = new Date(today);
    t1.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    //Calculate the ms difference between two date
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(t2.getTime() - t1.getTime());
    // 24*3600*1000 is milliseconds in a day
    var days_left = Math.round(difference_ms/(24*3600*1000));

    //Put the days_left to cert_details array
    cert_details.days_left = days_left;
    cert_details.exp_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(exp_date), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")

    
    if (days_left == 30) {
      console.log(cert_details.employee_name+"'s permit is expiring in 30 days");
     sendEmail(cert_details);
    }

sendEmail(cert_details);
/*
    else if (days_left == 3) {
      console.log(cert_details.employee_name+" expired in 3 days");
      sendEmail(cert_details);
    }
    else if (days_left == 7) {
      console.log(cert_details.employee_name+" expired in 7 days");
      sendEmail(cert_details);
    }
    else if (days_left == 30) {
      console.log(cert_details.employee_name+" expired in 30 days");
      sendEmail(cert_details);
    }

*/
  }
}



function sendEmail(cert_details){


  //Get the html email template
  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('EmailTemplatetest');
  templ.cert_details = cert_details;

  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: cert_details.email_primary,
    subject: "Permit Expiry Reminder: "+cert_details.employee_name+"'s permit expires in " +cert_details.days_left + " day(s)",
    htmlBody: message
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve your problem, It might give you an overall idea about the solution, rest you may figure out or ask me for more explaination.

```
// the input users json object or array

var users = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "123@gmail.com",
        "expire": "2019-01-01",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "234@gmail.com",
        "expire": "2019-12-01",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "email": "12423@gmail.com",
        "expire": "2021-12-01",
    }
]

// create the user stack for storing the users that are about to expire
var userStack = [];

users.forEach(function(user) {
    var expire = new Date(user.expire);

    // get the day difference between the current date and the user's expire date
    // (1000 * 3600 * 24) is to convert the milliseconds to days
    // Math.abs is to get the absolute value of the difference not the negative value
    var dayDiff = Math.abs((expire.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

    // comparison of minimum days
    if(dayDiff < 30) {
        userStack.push(user);
    }
});

// do something with that userStack 
console.log(userStack);

// i am gonna create a sample email message
var emailMessage = "";
// loop through the userStack
userStack.forEach(function(user, index) {
    // this will create something like a line by line message table
    emailMessage += index.toString() + ": User " + user.id + " will expire in " + user.expire + "\n";
});

// now you can send the email message to a perticular email address

MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "<Your Email Address>",
    subject: "The Expiration tables for the users",
    htmlBody: emailMessage
  });
```

Comment: This would still send an email for each row wouldn't it ?

Comment: So you want to mail, the whole table to one mail only

Comment: The just try to create a stack and push every person that comes into criteria into the stack, then construct a html kind table from it, and mail that to the email you want

Comment: I'm struggling with this part 'create a stack and push every person that comes into criteria into the stack, then construct a html kind table from it'

New to javascript . Do you mind helping me please ?

Comment: @VinK I have updated the solution